# Find row where multiple criteria are met, return a different column, for a full dataset

Tags: r

I have two datasets; 'data' and 'noiseaware'. noiseaware contains a RoomCode and a time stamp.

```
RoomCode last_trigger
GTX-513  2020-05-09 00:30:28
```

data contains a ton of things, including a reservation code, a check-in time stamp, a check-out time stamp, and a RoomCode. Ie

```
ReservationID RoomCode checkin_time         checkOutDate 
25307070gawgw GTX-513  2020-04-09 00:30:28  2020-05-09 00:30:28
```

My objective is that for each line in noiseaware, I want to find the corresponding reservation ID that matches the following combination:

1. Is after the checkInDate
2. Is before the checkOutDate
3. Has the same RoomCode

That in logic is as follows:

```
noiseaware$last_trigger <= data$checkOutDate & noiseaware$last_trigger >= data$checkInDate & data$RoomCode == noiseaware$RoomCode
```

However, I can't work out how to turn that logic - which returns a vector of true and false values - into something that returns the ReservationId. If it makes any difference, there should only be one matching ID for the above criteria.

Once I can do that, I'd then want to loop through and do the same for each line in noiseaware. I suppose I could do that with lapply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something `dplyr` can handle easily.
You will need to `left_join` table `noiseaware` to `data` by `RoomCode`.
And then filter out the samples you don't need.

Here's an example. Without a sample data, I have no way to test this. You may need to tweak these codes to accommodate the actual data. But the basic idea is there.

```
library("dplyr")

noiseaware %>% 
  left_join(data, by = "RoomCode") %>% 
  filter(last_trigger > checkin_time & last_trigger < checkOutDate)
```

Comment: I got the following error: 'Error: object 'checkin_time' not found'. I don't usually use %>% so I'm struggling to debug it. last_trigger is in noiseaware and the other two are in data, if it makes any difference?

Comment: Is 'checkin_time' in your tables?

Comment: Oops, it was checkInDate! Got it working, thanks! If I wanted to modify the left_join to only return certain columns, I believe I should use a select. I tried putting a select around 'data' but I seem to still be doing it wrong as it returns 'no applicable method for 'selet' applied to an object of class "character". `noiseaware3 <- noiseaware2 %>% 
  left_join(select(c(data$RoomCode, data$X_id)), by = "RoomCode") %>% 
  filter(last_trigger > checkInDate & last_trigger < checkOutDate)`

Comment: @Adam `... %>% left_join(...) %>% select(RoomCode, X_id) %>% ...`

Comment: `Error in select(., RoomCode, X_id) : unused arguments (RoomCode, X_id)`

Comment: or `... %>% left_join(...) %>% dplyr::select(RoomCode, X_id) %>% ...`?

Comment: Getting the same thing :( `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x The column `X_id` doesn't exist.` Those columns definitely exist in data.

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(noiseaware)[, last_trigger := 
    setDT(data)[.SD, on=.(RoomCode, checkInDate<=last_trigger, checkOutDate>=last_trigger), 
    mult="last", x.ReservationID]
]
```

`mult="last"` uses the last observation if there are multiple results for a row in `noiseaware`.

Comment: Hmm, I got the following error:  `Error in `:=`(last_trigger, data[.SD, on = .(RoomCode, checkInDate <=  : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").`

Comment: You need to setDT on both noiseaware and data

Comment: Would that be `library(data.table)
setDT(noiseaware, data)[, last_trigger := 
    setDT(data)[.SD, on=.(RoomCode, checkInDate<=last_trigger, checkOutDate>=last_trigger), 
    mult="last", x.ReservationID]
]`

Comment: The first argument of setDT is a data.frame and second is not. Right now it does not take in a ... list of data.frames